# Submitting form from R to mixed HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, r, rcurl, httr

I am trying to subit a query to http://revigo.irb.hr/ from R, and I am having a hard time.  It seems the page is a mix of HTML and Javascript, which is complicating a simple postForm() solution.  The query is a string (or list of strings) like "GO:0004432", and the results page has a link "Export results to text table (CSV) " to download data as a .csv.  The following code using httr doesn't seem to be returning anything from the page that would appear after submitting a query:

```
library(httr)
url <- "http://revigo.irb.hr/" 
fd <- list(
    submit = "Start Revigo",
    goList1="GO:0004432"
)
resp<-POST(url, body=fd, encode="form")
resp

Response [http://revigo.irb.hr/]
Date: 2015-08-20 15:57
Status: 200
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Size: 18.5 kB

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> REVIGO summarizes and visualizes long lists of Gene Ontology terms...
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" >       </scri...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js...
```

How does one approach such a task? I imagine the workflow to look something like:
get url, assign parameters (textarea, radio buttons, etc, submit button), run something like getForm with the url and params, search resulting page for link to .csv, and run read.csv() on that url.

My background is in R, and have a very, very minimal understanding of HTML and Javascript. Looking at past questions, it looks like either RSelenium, RCurl, or httr, or another package would be best.  Any recommendations or links to pertinent questions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help:

```
require(RSelenium)
url <- "http://revigo.irb.hr/"
checkForServer()
startServer()
fprof <- getFirefoxProfile("firefoxprofile",useBase = TRUE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName="firefox",extraCapabilities = fprof)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
webElem <- remDr$findElement("id","goList1")
keys <- c("GO:0042273","GO:0009853")
for (gene in keys){
  webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(gene,key="enter"))
}
webElem <- remDr$findElement("name","startRevigo")
webElem$clickElement()
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using="xpath","/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a[1]")
webElem$clickElement()
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(5000)
table1 <- read.csv("REVIGO.csv")
file.remove("REVIGO.csv")
remDr$close()
```

Here I have used a firefox profile which contains the information that whenever a csv file is downloaded, it downloads automatically in the working directory. I suggest you create a similar profile either by using makeFirefoxProfile and passisng arguments

```
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = getwd(),
                                 browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting = FALSE,
                                 browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = "text/csv"))
```

Or you can just use the existing firefox profile by using *getFirefoxProfile()* like I did over here.